# (array of structure pointer) decay

Tags: c, arrays, pointer-arithmetic

```
struct Node * leftright(struct Node **head,struct Node *mid)
    {   struct Node *temp=*head;
        struct Node *ret[2];
        ret[0] = malloc(  sizeof(temp));
        ret[1] = malloc(  sizeof(temp)); 
        while((temp->next)!=mid)
        {
            temp=temp->next;

        }

        temp->next=NULL;
        (ret)->next=*head;
        ret[1]->next =mid;
       printList(ret[0]->next);
       printList(ret[1]->next);
       return ret[0];
    }
```

In this code , to separate left and right sub list for merge sort.
I have used array of structure pointers.But why in this case ret is not deacying to the first element.
If i use (*ret)->next=*head; or  ret[0] code works.

Also if i use "(*ret)->next=*head;" version and use pointer arithmetic "((*ret)+1)->next =mid;" i dont get right list printed.
I probably suspect that *ret reduces to (*ret)[2].But why this happens and not simple decay is confusing me.

Thanks

Comment: `ret[0] = malloc(  sizeof(temp));` Is not needed. The array  can store two pointers, and you allocate space for two pointers, and store them there. Also: your function should return something (a pointer)

Comment: Its throwing segmentation fault when i remove  the two malloc.Anyways i dont understand is ret equivalant to **p or *p or(*p)[2].                                         
Yes ,i removed return by mistake.

Comment: If your intention is to split the list in two parts, why dont you just cut when `mid` is reached, and return the second part? (the first part will not change by cutting off the tail)

Comment: Thnks.But i am trying to learn pointer concepts by playing around the code.

Comment: Besides: the function assumes that the caller already *knows* mid, so the only task of this function is to set **one** pointer to NULL: the one that points to mid.